# Merge two values

Tags: code-golf

You have two values each of which is either `0` representing "unknown", or one of `1,2,3`. Merge them into a single value as follows:

- If both values are nonzero and equal, output that value:
  `(3,3) -> 3`
- If both values are nonzero but unequal, output 0 for unknown:
  `(1,2) -> 0`
- If one value is zero and the other is not, output the nonzero value:
  `(2,0) -> 2, (0,1) -> 1`
- If both values are zero, output zero:
  `(0,0) -> 0`

**Test cases:**

There are 16 possible input pairs.

```
  | 0 1 2 3
--+--------
0 | 0 1 2 3
1 | 1 1 0 0
2 | 2 0 2 0
3 | 3 0 0 3

(0, 0) -> 0
(0, 1) -> 1
(0, 2) -> 2
(0, 3) -> 3
(1, 0) -> 1
(1, 1) -> 1
(1, 2) -> 0
(1, 3) -> 0
(2, 0) -> 2
(2, 1) -> 0
(2, 2) -> 2
(2, 3) -> 0
(3, 0) -> 3
(3, 1) -> 0
(3, 2) -> 0
(3, 3) -> 3
```

### Leaderboards

```js
var QUESTION_ID=165314,OVERRIDE_USER=8478;function answersUrl(e){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(e,s){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+s.join(";")+"/comments?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],e.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var s=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(s),answers_hash[s]=e}),e.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){e.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),e.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){var e=[];answers.forEach(function(s){var r=s.body;s.comments.forEach(function(e){OVERRIDE_REG.test(e.body)&&(r="<h1>"+e.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var a=r.match(SCORE_REG);a&&e.push({user:getAuthorName(s),size:+a[2],language:a[1],link:s.share_link})}),e.sort(function(e,s){var r=e.size,a=s.size;return r-a});var s={},r=1,a=null,n=1;e.forEach(function(e){e.size!=a&&(n=r),a=e.size,++r;var t=jQuery("#answer-template").html();t=t.replace("{{PLACE}}",n+".").replace("{{NAME}}",e.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",e.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",e.size).replace("{{LINK}}",e.link),t=jQuery(t),jQuery("#answers").append(t);var o=e.language;/<a/.test(o)&&(o=jQuery(o).text()),s[o]=s[o]||{lang:e.language,user:e.user,size:e.size,link:e.link}});var t=[];for(var o in s)s.hasOwnProperty(o)&&t.push(s[o]);t.sort(function(e,s){return e.lang>s.lang?1:e.lang<s.lang?-1:0});for(var c=0;c<t.length;++c){var i=jQuery("#language-template").html(),o=t[c];i=i.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",o.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",o.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",o.size).replace("{{LINK}}",o.link),i=jQuery(i),jQuery("#languages").append(i)}}var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=/<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/,OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Comment: The fourth rule fits in the first rule, so I dont know why you separated them.

Comment: Nitpick: The 4th point is redundant, you can just remove "nonzero" from the first point. EDIT: Wow, what a ninja @Fatalize is.

Comment: Also, 3 isn't really necessary here, although it does increase the number of possible inputs.

Comment: You say the 4th rule fits in the first rule, but I see it as redundant with the third rule.

Comment: I considered condensing the rules, but thought it would be clearest to just list all the zero/nonzero cases and leave the optimization up to the golfers.

Comment: This needs a [leaderboard](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5139/), the first page is starting to get answers already beaten on the second one.

Comment: Good idea, could you please one? I only have mobile access for some time.

Comment: Thanks for the leaderboard, although... are other people seeing the languages with links wrongly alphabetized?

Answer (score 24):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>27</s> 25 bytes

```python
lambda x,y:(x|y)>>(x*y&2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fpmCrEPM/JzE3KSVRoUKn0kqjoqZS085Oo0KrUs1I839afpFChUJmnkJRYl56qoaJphUXJ0isEk2Ms6AoM69EI02jQkehUlNHITUvxVZdQV2TCyqh@R8A)

Comment: I like that this breaks for inputs over 3. How did you come up with this?

Comment: Basically lots of trial and error.

Comment: Interesting. For a moment I thought of automating a search through limited-length expressions involving two ints and a few operators, but the space is much too big even at around 20 bytes. Some intelligence is required!

Answer (score 16):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
gf|S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z89rSb4v8nDHdsOLz@8L8H9PwA)

#### How it works

```
gf|S  Main link. Left argument: x. Right argument: y.

g     Compute a, the gcd of x and y.
  |   Compute b, the bitwise OR of x and y.
 f    Filter; yield all common elements of [a] and [b].
   S  Take the sum.
```

Answer (score 10):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 5 bytes

```apl
⌈×∧=⌊
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AS0A0v9hcGwtZHlhbG9n//9m4oaQ4oyIw5fiiKc94oyK///iiJguZuKNqDAgMSAyIDM)

Useful [reference](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/151368/71256)

`∧=⌊`: Returns `1` if the lowest common multiple is equal to the minimum. This is only true if one of the values is zero, or both are equal. Alternatively I could have `=*⌊`

`⌈×`: The maximum multiplied by the above.

Answer (score 8):

## [Shakespeare Programming Language](http://shakespearelang.sourceforge.net/report/shakespeare/), 296 bytes

```
Z.Ford,.Ajax,.Act I:.Scene I:.[Enter Ford and Ajax]Ajax:Listen to thy heart.Ford:Listen to thy heart.Am I as fat as you?Ajax:If so,let us Scene C.Am I as fat as zero?If so,let us Scene C.Ford:Am I as fat as zero?If not,you zero.open heart.let us Scene V.Scene C:.Ajax:open heart.Scene V:.[Exeunt]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZDPCoMwDMbve4o8gJTBbr2IyAbCbgMPGx6KRtxwjbQp6F6@s9XDNtwlf8iP70tih977qziRaRKRPdQ4x5qhkOJSo8ZQ3I6a0UBAQOkGAlWFIM93y6iBCbiboENlOCptDrInFKAstIpDmsilUaRowVLSI4OzsJjmv/ALDaWbYLT7Q2viZLaJvaBhXmjZ5EuiXA/NZTxffnArED4wotNceX/Y7d8)

First participation to a code-golf challenge, so let's start with one of my favorite joke languages !

Explanation :
Declaration of the two variables Ford and Ajax (shortest variable names available)

```
Z.Ford,.Ajax,.
```

First Scene : Put the two values into the variable, then test them for equality, then test Ajax against 0. If the value that we have to return is stored in the variable Ford, go to Scene C.

```
Act I:.
Scene I:.
[Enter Ford and Ajax]
Ajax:
Listen to thy heart.
Ford:Listen to thy heart.
Am I as fat as you?
Ajax:
If so,let us Scene C.
Am I as fat as zero?
If so,let us Scene C.
```

If Ford is 0, print Ajax, else set Ajax as 0 then print Ajax. Then go to the end of the program.

```
Ford:Am I as fat as zero?
If not,you zero.
open heart.
let us Scene V.
```

Scene C : Print Ford

```
Scene C:.
Ajax:open heart.
```

Scene V: End of the program.

```
Scene V:.
[Exeunt]
```

Comment: [221 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZY4/CwIxDMV3P8VzPwq3usgNCgXBwVEc4jXHKV5ztDn88@Vrq6CCU17yfslLHC8pVaY5060yawku61ZhF2bXsuci9iuvHFAQkHco1KF0i80pKnuooGcKOi/O37AZYEERR3Kl3GVa2g5Rqqzw4CDGRmjPGIO4KWdLV6C8dJUQGYSW9GeFAr/wOA0f1GTbi35Pbsf8wjs/pXpWPwE "Shakespeare Programming Language – Try It Online")

Comment: @JoKing your version is undeniably better than mine, I think it would be better if you posted it as an answer as the reasoning behind the program is quite different and I don't want to take the credit for your work

Answer (score 6):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 21 bytes

```ruby
->a,b{(a|b)*531[a*b]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y5RJ6laI7EmSVPL1NgwOlErKbb2f0FpSbGChoGenrGmXm5iQXVNYg0yL6kmLRqoLbZWS11BvfY/AA)

Because Ruby

## Short explanation:

- `a|b` is bitwse OR, so it gives us the right number if a==b or one of them is zero.
- Magic number `531` is 2^9+2^4+2^1+2^0, and the [] operator extracts a single bit. This means: multiply by 1 if a*b is 0, 1, 2, 4 or 9, multiply by 0 otherwise.
- This won't work for values > 3

Answer (score 6):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 25 bytes

```hs
x!y=0^((x-y)^2*x)*y+0^y*x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/v0Kx0tYgTkOjQrdSM85Iq0JTq1LbIK5Sq@J/bmJmnoKtQko@l4JCbmKBb7xCQVFmXolCdDRQj0KNQoWCja5CtIGennFsLJBbicT9DwA)

Answer (score 6):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <s>8</s> 7 bytes

```
@{+0SQ3
```

[Try it online!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%40%7B%2B0SQ3&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B3%2C3%5D%0A%5B1%2C2%5D%0A%5B1%2C0%5D%0A%5B0%2C1%5D%0A%5B0%2C0%5D&debug=0)

```
@{+0SQ3   Implicit: Q=input()

    SQ    Sort input
  +0      Prepend 0
 {        Deduplicate
@     3    Get 4th element (index 3), modular indexing
```

**Case 1 - Both values nonzero and equal**

```
Sorted Input   [3,3]
Prepend 0      [0,3,3]
Deduplicate    [0,3] - index 3 yields 3
```

**Case 2 - Both values nonzero and unequal**

```
Sorted Input   [1,2]
Prepend 0      [0,1,2]
Deduplicate    [0,1,2] - index 3 yields 0
```

**Case 3 - Exactly one value zero**

```
Sorted Input   [0,1]
Prepend 0      [0,0,1]
Deduplicate    [0,1] - index 3 yields 1
```

**Case 4 - Both values zero**

```
Sorted Input   [0,0]
Prepend 0      [0,0,0]
Deduplicate    [0] - index 3 yields 0
```

---

*Alternate solution, also 7 bytes*

```
*eSQ}s{
```

[Try it online](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2AeSQ%7Ds%7B&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B3%2C3%5D%0A%5B1%2C2%5D%0A%5B1%2C0%5D%0A%5B0%2C1%5D%0A%5B0%2C0%5D&debug=0)

```
*eSQ}s{QQ   Trailing Q's inferred

      {Q    Deduplicate input
     s      Take the sum
    }   Q   Is this in the input? True treated as 1, false as 0
*           Multiplied by
 eSQ        Max from input (end of sorted input)
```

---

*Previous version, 8 bytes*

```
@+0{-QZ3
```

Comment: @xnor Thanks for spotting that, it should be fixed now

Comment: `@{+0Q3` works for 6 bytes.

Answer (score 5):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 17 bytes, port somehow from Python answer

```javascript
a=>b=>a*b&2?0:a|b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/e9m@z/R1i7J1i5RK0nNyN7AKrEm6X9yfl5xfk6qXk5@uka0np6eY1FRYqWGiWasXm5igYZGvE6mpq0dVoksoISbRqamRpYmEPwHAA)

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 21 bytes

```javascript
a=>b=>a-b?a*b?0:a+b:a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/e9m@z/R1i7J1i5RN8k@USvJ3sAqUTvJKvF/cn5ecX5Oql5OfrqGm4aBpoaxpuZ/AA)

Comment: `?0:`... Could you do `||`, or does precedence mess that up?

Comment: @StanStrum `?0:` mean return zero if cond is not zero, `||` return non-zero if cond is not zero

Answer (score 5):

## Java 8, 20 bytes

Curried lambda. [Stolen from here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/165326).

```java
a->b->(a|b)>>(a*b&2)
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
Ç∞∟∙◄╥*♣
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=80ec1cf911d22a05&i=[0,+0]%0A[0,+1]%0A[0,+2]%0A[0,+3]%0A[1,+0]%0A[1,+1]%0A[1,+2]%0A[1,+3]%0A[2,+0]%0A[2,+1]%0A[2,+2]%0A[2,+3]%0A[3,+0]%0A[3,+1]%0A[3,+2]%0A[3,+3]&a=1&m=2)

Unpacked, ungolfed, and commented, it looks like this.

```
    e.g.        [2, 0]
c:s [2, 0] 2    calculate the "span" of the input array (max(a) - min(a))
+   [2, 0, 2]   append the span to the input array
o   [0, 2, 2]   sort the 3-element array
E   0 2 2       explode the 3 elements into 3 separate stack entries
a   2 2 0       rotate the third stack element to the top of stack
!   2 2 1       logical not, produces 1 iff the top value was 0
*   2 2         multiply
                implicitly print top of stack
```

[Run this one](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=+++%09e.g.+++++%09[2,+0]%0Ac%3As%09[2,+0]+2+%09calculate+the+%22span%22+of+the+input+array+%28max%28a%29+-+min%28a%29%29%0A%2B++%09[2,+0,+2]%09append+the+span+to+the+input+array%0Ao++%09[0,+2,+2]%09sort+the+3-element+array%0AE++%090+2+2++++%09explode+the+3+elements+into+3+separate+stack+entries%0Aa++%092+2+0++++%09rotate+the+third+stack+element+to+the+stop%0A%21++%092+2+1++++%09logical+not,+produces+1+iff+the+top+value+was+0%0A*++%092+2++++++%09multiply%0A+++%09+++++++++%09implicitly+print+top+of+stack&i=[0,+0]%0A[0,+1]%0A[0,+2]%0A[0,+3]%0A[1,+0]%0A[1,+1]%0A[1,+2]%0A[1,+3]%0A[2,+0]%0A[2,+1]%0A[2,+2]%0A[2,+3]%0A[3,+0]%0A[3,+1]%0A[3,+2]%0A[3,+3]&a=1&m=2)

Answer (score 4):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 32 bytes

```
{(({}[({})]<>)){{}<>}(<>)}{}({})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/v1pDo7o2Gog1Y23sNDWrq2tt7Go1gMza6lqQ6P//RgrGAA)

Answer (score 4):

(first submission so please don't kick too hard)

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <strike>57 44</strike> 43 bytes

```python
lambda a,b:(0 if a*b else a+b)if a-b else a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XctBCsIwEEbhfU7xg5tGI0xmdkJu4maCCRZqLTYbTx9TwVBcfg/e8i7358w1B1zrpI94U6iLl4EwZugxIk1rgp6i3Xz@uRpzQElrMctrnAvyIE5sCNLtHTdTNztq5m5yvtnvfmwBtC9s8Z/km6R@AA)

(compressed a bit after looking at [first python](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/165326/80759) answer)

Comment: [33 bytes](https://tio.run/##Xcu9CsIwFIbhPVfxkenkD2x1KuZOOuQEjaZoWkIXofceUeriOz/v8lrvc@lb8hjbg5/xwmAbB2Idz53SxCYqQ@x9VJrbUnNZJbDhgA49jmNxzrg9KUSaKzJyQeVyu9JJDQLfCSEHI7FJK/BB0x/6qUTZTirYfWtv)

Comment: *Crossed out 44 is still 44 ;(*

Comment: @JoKing huh wut? Your solution is great, i tried to do it with arithmetics, but failed and fell back to if/else

Answer (score 4):

## C (gcc), 25 bytes

`f(a,b){a=a^b&&a*b?0:a|b;}`

pseudo-code:

```
foo(A,B)
    if A XOR B and A*B are > 0
        return 0
    else 
        return A OR B`
```

Answer (score 3):

## C (gcc), 26 bytes

```
f(a,b){a=a*b?a-b?0:a:a+b;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZBBDoIwEEX3nGKiMQFpDSorEDkIsGhBtESLUXQDPTsOiIqKTpqZRX/emzam2ziu61RnhBsl89iU@4xy33KYw0zuqnosZLy/JBtYnYtE5LPdWhOygAMTUr/mIjGg1KCr5oIFdgQelBaBOYEFgaVy3wL8X@B4wkiqjwAqmCTPE0pKTdpVKEcENVbU9HnbF21fRsaLlOYn0BufQJnl4liB7YJpiv7Gn160VYB4Hog@7Aua3aHZA5oNQQfgiMa/DrKoUww41M/l8OG9vNJUfQM)

Expanation / Ungolfed:

```
int f(int a, int b) { // implicit-int (C89)
    // return replaced with assignment: link
    return a*b ? // if a and b are both not zero, then
        a-b ? // if a != b
        0 : // a != b, so return 0
        a // a == b, so return a
    : a+b // one of a,b is zero, so return whichever is nonzero 
    ;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 9 bytes

```
dGp*~GX>*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P8W9QKvOPcJO6///aAMdo1gA)

#### Explanation:

```
           % Implicit input as a vector with two elements implicitly. Stack: [0,2]
d          % The difference between the two elements. Stack: [2]
 G         % Push input again. Stack: [2], [0,2]
  p        % The product of the last element (the input). Stack: [2], [0]
   *       % Multiply the two elements on the stack. Stack: [0]
    ~      % Negate. Stack: [1]
     G     % Push input again. Stack: [1], [0,2]
      X>   % Maximum value. Stack: [1], [2]
        *  % Multiply the two elements on the stack. Stack: [2]
           % Implicit output
```

Comment: Failed outgolf: [`t?td~*]X>`](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/v8S@JKVOKzbC7v//aEMdo1gA)

Answer (score 3):

## GNU sed, 23 bytes

```
s/^0?(.)\1?0?$/\1/
t
c0
```

(must be run with `-r` flag)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcGxDcJAEETR/NdBgANzM7sFXCMWCSBEYls@0z7Le@P1nN/rt/Ya7a5@vU2Lu/qlLW6cPFQlIaNAiYWNAychwkQQSYo0GWT@tv38bOuo@fgD)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG :) The current consensus is that flags not be counted (I'm on my phone so can't link the relevant Meta).

Comment: Oh cool! I'll edit later since I'm also on my phone; a free -3 bytes is a great welcome to PPCG :)

Answer (score 3):

## QBasic, 34 bytes

Different approach!

```
INPUT a,b
?(a OR b)*-(a*b=0OR a=b)
```

Observe that the nonzero values in the output grid are all the bitwise `OR` of the two input numbers. This is just `a OR b` in QBasic. We want to output this value when `a*b=0 OR a=b`, and `0` otherwise, which we can do by multiplying by the negative of the aforementioned conditional (negative, since truthy is `-1` in QBasic).

Answer (score 2):

### Batch, <s>38</s> <s>36</s> <s>35</s> 30 bytes

```
@cmd/cset/a"(%1|%2)>>(%1*%2&2)
```

Port of @Dennis's Python answer, as conditionals are too expensive in Batch.

Answer (score 2):

## [Swift](https://swift.org/), 118 bytes

```
func c(n1:Int,n2:Int){n1==n2 ? print("\(n1)") : (n1*n2 != 0 ? print("0") : (n1==0 ? print("\(n2)") : print("\(n1)")))}
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! I don't know Swift, but you can probably save a lot of bytes by making the variable names 1 character each, and removing whitespace around operators like `!=` and the ternary.

Comment: Hi, welcome to PPCG! As mentioned by @Οurous, you can change `n1` and `n2` to single chars to shorten them; remove some white-spaces and parenthesis, and remove some spaces. In addition, `==0` can be `<1` and `!=0` can be `>0`, since we know only the inputs `0,1,2,3` are possible. Never programmed in Swift before either, but I got it down to 91 bytes like this: `func c(a:Int,b:Int){a==b ?print("\(a)"):a*b>0 ?print("0"):a<1 ?print("\(b)"):print("\(a)")}` [Try it online.](https://tinyurl.com/yacjl3yy)

Comment: In addition, it seems you can shorten it to 51 bytes like this: `func c(a:Int,b:Int){print(a==b||a*b<1 ?max(a,b):0)}` [Try it online.](https://tio.run/##Ky7PTCsx@f8/rTQvWSFZI9HKM69EJwlEalYXFGXmlWgk2tom1dQkaiXZGCrY5yZWaCTqJGlaGWjW/k/LL1LIVMjMUzDQ09MzruZSUACJZKGIKChATFGK0cjUVIjRyNK0UlDSBEuAbMvUUUiyytJEUghi13LV/gcA) Again welcome to PPCG, and enjoy your stay!

Comment: In addition to @KevinCruijssen's golfs, you can turn your submission  into an anonymous closure to save 87 bytes: `{$0==$1||1>$0*$1 ?max($0,$1):0}` [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcpBCsIwEEbhfU/xU2YxIyFM0FUhepFuSqEwAavEYoU2Z490p7vHx3utNi2X@h4yRkTUjTRGCvserqQnCrjdhw@TOgrSaanTI8NgM9R7f94a4JD0J8Az27xw27MJek7SoXUY2RySyM9xdGlK/QI "Swift 4 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## brainfuck, 25 bytes

```
,>,[>]<<[[->->+<<]>[>]]>.
```

Input is two byte values (not ascii)

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <strike>8</strike> 7 bytes

1 byte saved by H.PWiz.

```
>.*=^<.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qfVmyrp2CgYKVg8N9OT8s2zkbvvyaXkp6CepqtnrqCjkKtlUJaMRdXanJGPlBZGhBD2EZIbEMg2xjCNEYw0/TV9Oyqresy9Uy4/gMA)

A J port of H.PWiz's APL solution

`=` are the numbers equal? (results in 1 or 0)

`^` to the power of

`<.` the smaller number

`*` multiplied by

`>.` the larger number

Comment: `>.*=^<.` for 7 bytes

Comment: @ H.PWiz Thank you! Clever use of `=` and`^`!

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>9</s> 8 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
àIËIP_+*
```

-1 byte thanks to *@MagicOctopusUrn*.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//8ALPw92eAfHaWv//RxvpGMcCAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##HcghDoAwDEDR@wBibcM98MtCIOE0XAKLmUPhOs@VyvLNEy/N2y5HfI/f0S6v7fS6rOMQxd/IOU2pTF1BResKL7zwwiuvvPLKG2@88da//A).

**Explanation:**

```
à         # Take the maximum of the input-list
          #  [0,2] → 2
IË        # Are all elements in the input-list equal?
          #  [0,2] → 0
  IP_     # Take the product of the input-list, and verify if it equals 0
          # (`_` transforms 0 into 1; everything else into 0)
          #  [0,2] → 0 (product) → 1 (==0)
     +    # Add them together (since only 1 is truthy in 05AB1E, this is basically an OR)
          #  0+1 → 1
*         # Multiply both values on the stack
          #  2*1 → 2
```

**Generalized explanation:**

```
IËIP_+    # If both values are equal, or one of them is a zero:
 à        #  Output the maximum of the two values
          # Else:
          #  Output 0
```

Comment: `Ës0å~iZë0` was mine; nice one. Not actually sure you can beat 9 bytes by much.

Comment: I take that back `à®Ë®P_+*` where `_` is logically equivalent to `>Θ`

Comment: `_` turns 0 into 1, all other values into 0.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn Thanks! When I made this answer I was looking at the docs to see if there was a `== 0` command, didn't knew `_` does exactly that. Should be useful for other challenges in the future as well. TIL. :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>34</s> 28 bytes

```python
lambda i,j:(i|j,0)[0<i!=j>0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSFTJ8tKI7MmS8dAM9rAJlPRNsvOIPZ/Wn6RQoVCZp5CUWJeeqqGiaaCFZcCEIDEK7GIg0BBUWZeiUJCRYKCtoKSjhKQTKgEsxVs7RTA3DSNCp1KzYT/AA)

-6 with thanks to @Dennis

Comment: `[0<i!=j>0]` saves a few bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 10 bytes

```
=h|∋0&⌉|∧0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/3zaj5lFHt4Hao55OIGO5wf//0cY6RrH/owA)

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript ES6, <strike>25</strike> <strike>22</strike> <strike>21</strike> 20 bytes

```
a=>b=>a?b-a?!b*a:a:b
```

**<strike>14</strike> 13 bytes**, If the arguments are provided in sorted order

```
a=>b=>a%b?0:b
```

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript, 35 bytes

```
f=(m,n)=>(m||n)&&(m!=n)?(m>n?m:n):0
```

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes

```
ê0ýÙ7è
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASoA1f8wNWFiMWX/M8Odw6N2eXl5/8OqMMO9w5k3w6j/eSLDvyAtPiDDvyIsXP8)

Port(ish) of [my Pyth answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/165434/41020).

*TIO header/footer taken from [Emigna's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/165358/41020)*

Answer (score 2):

## QBasic, <s>38</s> <s>36</s> 35 bytes

```
INPUT a,b
?(a*b>0)*(b-a*(a<>b))+a+b
```

Partly inspired by [Erik's `IF ... THEN ... ELSE` answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/167073/16766), here's a math-only solution.

#### How I got here

*Important note for understanding math-with-conditionals: in QBasic, the results of comparison operators are `0` and `-1`, not `0` and `1`.*

We start with Erik's code:

```
IF a*b THEN?a*-(a=b)ELSE?a+b
```

In other words, if `a` and `b` are both nonzero, then print `a*-(a=b)` (`a` if `a=b`, otherwise `0`); else (at least one of `a` and `b` is zero), output `a+b` (the nonzero number, or `0` if they're both zero).

There's already some math with conditionals going on here. Let's take it a step farther and see if we can eliminate the `IF` statement entirely. We'll have to use `a*b>0` for the outer condition: `a*b` can have multiple different truthy values, which is fine for `IF` but causes problems for math.

```
c=a*b>0
?c*a*(a=b)+(c+1)*(a+b)
```

This is the [standard trick](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166130/16766) of `IF`-elimination. When `c` is true, `c*a*(a=b)` is `-a*(a=b)` and `(c+1)*(a+b)` is `0`; when `c` is false, `c*a*(a=b)` is `0` and `(c+1)*(a+b)` is `a+b`. So this expression gives the same results as the `IF ... THEN ... ELSE`. The only problem is, it makes our program 40 bytes instead of 38. Maybe we can shorten it by rearranging the math.

```
c=a*b>0
?c*a*(a=b)+c*(a+b)+a+b
```

Still 40 bytes...

```
c=a*b>0
?c*(a+b+a*(a=b))+a+b
```

Now our program is back to 38 bytes. But since we're only using `c` once, we don't have to assign it to a variable anymore:

```
?(a*b>0)*(a+b+a*(a=b))+a+b
```

Now we're down to 36 bytes.

*But wait there's more...* That `a+b+a*(a=b)` expression looks a bit redundant. `a*(a=b)` is `-a` if `a=b` and `0` otherwise. When we add it to `a`, we get `0` if `a=b` and `a` otherwise. Maybe we can achieve the same thing in fewer bytes by reversing the condition.

```
b+a*-(a<>b)
```

At first, this doesn't look shorter. But we can save a byte by subtracting instead of adding a negative:

```
b-a*(a<>b)
```

And there we have our 35-byte solution.

Comment: Nice trick over there...

Answer (score 2):

## [Shakespeare Programming Language](https://github.com/TryItOnline/spl), 187 bytes

```
,.Ajax,.Puck,.Act I:.Scene I:.[Enter Ajax and Puck]Ajax:Listen tothy!Puck:Listen tothy!Be
you nicer zero?If notyou be I.Am I worse a cat?If notam I as big as you?If notyou zero.Open heart
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY0/CwIxDMX3@xRxP4rgdouc4FAQFBzFIVejV/@kR5tDzy9fG3DQKS@/vPeShnvOtWmv@KrNbnS3op2AbczeEZOKw5qFIqgFkE@grqNuzcYnIQYJ0k8zxf9kRdUURmDvSvxNMSztGTiIwq5Um/YBFp4hJgIEh/K9o2JM0PmLjmL/CWqP2Q7lSU8YJed5tfgA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 15 bytes

```
?0⁼?0⁼∨??⁼∨??∴*
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCI/MOKBvD8w4oG84oioPz/igbziiKg/P+KItCoiLCIiLCIxXG4yIl0=)

Surprisingly no Vyxal answer yet. Return the max, multiplied by the boolean value indicating whether the values are equal or one of them is zero.

---

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 6 bytes

```
s0pU3i
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCJgKDAsIDApIC0+IDBcbigwLCAxKSAtPiAxXG4oMCwgMikgLT4gMlxuKDAsIDMpIC0+IDNcbigxLCAwKSAtPiAxXG4oMSwgMSkgLT4gMVxuKDEsIDIpIC0+IDBcbigxLCAzKSAtPiAwXG4oMiwgMCkgLT4gMlxuKDIsIDEpIC0+IDBcbigyLCAyKSAtPiAyXG4oMiwgMykgLT4gMFxuKDMsIDApIC0+IDNcbigzLCAxKSAtPiAwXG4oMywgMikgLT4gMFxuKDMsIDMpIC0+IDNgXG5cbmBcXG5gLyBgIC1gLyB2aEUgXG7GmyIsInMwcFUzaSIsIm5TJFwiYCUgLT4gJWAkJTtgXFxuYGoiLCIiXQ==)

Thanks @lyxal for this version which ports the Pyth answer.

Comment: [Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCJgKDAsIDApIC0+IDBcbigwLCAxKSAtPiAxXG4oMCwgMikgLT4gMlxuKDAsIDMpIC0+IDNcbigxLCAwKSAtPiAxXG4oMSwgMSkgLT4gMVxuKDEsIDIpIC0+IDBcbigxLCAzKSAtPiAwXG4oMiwgMCkgLT4gMlxuKDIsIDEpIC0+IDBcbigyLCAyKSAtPiAyXG4oMiwgMykgLT4gMFxuKDMsIDApIC0+IDNcbigzLCAxKSAtPiAwXG4oMywgMikgLT4gMFxuKDMsIDMpIC0+IDNgXG5cbmBcXG5gLyBgIC1gLyB2aEUgXG7GmyIsIuKCjOKJiEHCrOKIqFtHfDAiLCJdblMkXCJgJSAtPiAlYCQlO2BcXG5gaiIsIiJd) for 9 bytes.

Comment: [or port Pyth](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCJgKDAsIDApIC0+IDBcbigwLCAxKSAtPiAxXG4oMCwgMikgLT4gMlxuKDAsIDMpIC0+IDNcbigxLCAwKSAtPiAxXG4oMSwgMSkgLT4gMVxuKDEsIDIpIC0+IDBcbigxLCAzKSAtPiAwXG4oMiwgMCkgLT4gMlxuKDIsIDEpIC0+IDBcbigyLCAyKSAtPiAyXG4oMiwgMykgLT4gMFxuKDMsIDApIC0+IDNcbigzLCAxKSAtPiAwXG4oMywgMikgLT4gMFxuKDMsIDMpIC0+IDNgXG5cbmBcXG5gLyBgIC1gLyB2aEUgXG7GmyIsInMwcFUzaSIsIm5TJFwiYCUgLT4gJWAkJTtgXFxuYGoiLCIiXQ==) for 6 bytes

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>12</s> 9 bytes

Takes input as an array of integers.

```
×&2?0:Ur|
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn///B0NSN7A6vQopr//6MNdAxjAQ)

Comment: I had the same, but with logical OR (`ª`) instead of bitwise.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>7</s> 6 bytes

```
×¬o=a»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///w9ENr8m0TD@3@//@/wX8jAA) or [Try all combinations!](https://tio.run/##ARsA5P9qZWxsef//w5fCrG89YcK7/zPFu8Onw75gR/8)

**How?**

```
×¬o=a»   Dyadic link
×        Multiply the two arguments.
 ¬       Logical not. Gives 1 if one argument is 0, 1 otherwise.
   =     Are the two arguments equal?
  o      Logical or the result of = and ¬. 
     »   Greater of the two arguments.
    a    Logical and. Gives the greater of the two arguments if they are equal
         or if one of them is zero and gives 0 otherwise.
```

Using the method in the [APL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/165318/75553), we get the same byte count. One byte longer than that answer because lowest common multiple is two bytes.

**6 bytes**

```
«=æl×»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARwA4/9qZWxsef//wqs9w6Zsw5fCu/8zxbvDp8O@YEf/)

Comment: I also note an alternate method below

Comment: @H.PWiz Oh, I thought you were using the same method as the one in the link

Comment: I give two methods `∧=⌊` and `=*⌊`. The second of which is prefered by Jelly

Comment: @H.PWiz I don't speak APL, I was just using the method you described. What does `=*⌊` do?

Comment: It's pretty much the same as Jelly, except that `⌊` is minimum. Or one could use `×` in both languages

Answer (score 1):

## [Clean](https://github.com/Ourous/curated-clean-linux), <s>46</s> <s>43</s> 42 bytes

```
import StdEnv
?[a,b]|a<1||a==b=b=0
```

```
?o sort
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85JTcz7n5ufUpqTqpCbmJn3PzO3IL@oRCG4JMU1r4zLPjpRJym2JtHGsKYm0dY2CQgN/geXJBaVcCkrpJXmJZdk5ucp2CrY5ysUA7Vx2SIEo410DGL//0tOy0lML/6v6@nz36UyLzE3M7kYAA)

Anonymous composition `:: [Int] -> Int`, sorts the pair and then matches off the first member.

Doing it as a composed lambda is the same length:

```
import StdEnv
```

```
(\[a,b]|a<1||a==b=b=0)o sort
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 30 bytes

```python
lambda a,b:0==a*b*(a-b)and a|b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XcxBCsIwFATQfU4xZJP8mkC1rgq5STc/tNEU/S2lG6F3j2gVxIHZvZn5sV4naUoKXbnxPfYMdrGtQ@AqVpZ9JJYevMUyL1lWq4ENNY44oenE@4P/RJNSaVqQkQULy2WwZ2oV9tm75PQG7QbpgzGk8OLjH//xyWY3Eu0ehvA9o/IE)

-5 bytes thanks to Oliver
-1 byte thanks to Jo King

Answer (score 1):

## TI-Basic, 10 bytes

```
max(Ans)not(prod(Ans)ΔList(Ans
```

Multiply maximum value by result of (some element equals zero OR elements are equal)

Comment: Yay for opcodes!

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 22 bytes

```c
f(x,y){x=x*y&2?0:x|y;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Rc5BDoIwFATQdXuKHwymlWoQXFGQs5hitYkWg5D0Bzl7LXbhapJ5sxi1vynlvWZOIJ9d43a4Ldq8ch@Ui98Yqx5Td4X6PXamP9zPlBo7wvNiLON0pkT3A7C1ctBALkPUcAqRZZySv2JUjIpRyWsIplmSTqlKBKwnALn4zUpooSyggmPOJV38Fw)

Comment: Does this produce output?

Comment: In gcc and without optimizations, yes. It's undefined behavior though. It works because gcc computes `x*y&2?0:x|y` in the eax register, which is where a proper `return` statement would move it.

Comment: Ah, right. Shouldn't the language of this submission be C (GCC) on x86 then? Or is that not the established convention?

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 27 bytes

```hs
a#b=max a b*0^(a*b*(a-b)^2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P1E5yTY3sUIhUSFJyyBOI1ErSUsjUTdJM85I839uYmaegq1CbmKBb7xCQVFmXolCdDRQg0INULmNrkK0gZ6ecWxsTZKNLpT5HwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 28 bytes

```matlab
@(a,b)~(a*b*(a~=b))*max(a,b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999BI1EnSbNOI1ErSUsjsc42SVNTKzexAiz6Py2/SCHT1tDKWAfEygKzFFIyiws0ojN1snTSNICkZqymTmpeCgj/BwA)

or

```matlab
@(a,b)(a==b|~(a*b))*max(a,b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999BI1EnSVMj0dY2qaZOI1ErSVNTKzexAiz6Py2/SCHT1sDKWAfEygKzFFIyiws0ojN1snTSNICkZqymTmpeCgj/BwA)

---

#### Explanation:

The maximum value should be outputted if `a*b=0` or if `a==b`. The function takes `a` and `b` as inputs. It multiplies `a*b`, thus getting a zero if one of them is zero, and checks that `a~=b`, thus getting a zero if the two are equal. We negate both, so that both conditions gives us a truthy value telling us that we should output the maximum value. We then multiply this boolean (`0/1`) by the maximum value, and outputs it.

Comment: [26 bytes](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999BI1EnSbNOI1EtSS2xzjZJUys3sQIs9j8tv0gh09bAylgHxMoCsxRSMosLNKIzdbJ00jSApGaspk5qXgoI/wcA)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 7 bytes

```
`α*P_*Z
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/W98eO7hxWWVlZX/E85t1AqI14r6X6l0eL@Crp3C4f1KOjH/AQ)

**Explanation**

```
`α        # absolute difference of the inputs
  *       # multiplied by the inputs
   P      # product of the result
    _     # logically negated
     *    # multiplied by the inputs
      Z   # max
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6)

### 27 bytes

A rather long formula, but without any conditional statement.

```javascript
a=>b=>(a|4)*(b|4)*6%61%27&3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/R1i7J1k4jscZEU0sjCUSaqZoZqhqZqxn/T87PK87PSdXLyU/X4FJQiDbQMdQx0jGO1ctNLNBIVLC1AwqiCycBhRXSNBI1NZI0NfWy8jPzNNQV1DWBKmG8mDwgV/M/AA)

### 17 bytes

Simply a port of [Dennis' method](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/165326/58563).

```javascript
a=>b=>a*b&2?0:a|b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/R1i7J1i5RK0nNyN7AKrEm6X9yfl5xfk6qXk5@ugaXgkK0gY6hjpGOcaxebmKBRqKCrR1QEF04CSiskKaRqKmRpKmpl5WfmaehrqCuCVQJ48XkAbma/wE)

Answer (score 1):

## [Elixir](https://elixir-lang.org/), 34 bytes

Pretty simple in a functional programming language, just get the first match. No maths here!

```
fn a,a->a
a,0->a
0,a->a
_,_->0 end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY6xCgMhEER7v2KxWsET8wGxT5UibUDkshFBjHh7kOL@3XgJhKQa5jE8hnJ6ptYjsU@lrgxHuBeYHJzOZsAFpVSwObhwSyWaRjWHmTy3kPIAKK9Favgf8WO4mCI1VEDlJrAPZ9BhckEEbfewn@a1n5zdR10Z/L4wqDT8NiW296VUlkozo@pWHF4)

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), <s>20</s> 18 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to Martin Ender.

```
(.)\1|0
$1
..|^$
0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcGhDYBAEERR/@uA5DCXmd0iaIIQEAgMgiCv9@W99/ru56y5rUe1vmweYjK9j31CVRIyCpRY2DhwEiJMBJGkSJNB5g8)

Comment: You can save two bytes by combining the stages a bit: https://tio.run/##BcGhDYBAEERR/@uA5DCXmd0iaIIQEAgMgiCv9@W99/ru56y5rUe1vmweYjK9j31CVRIyCpRY2DhwEiJMBJGkSJNB5g8

Comment: @MartinEnder This looks a lot better now, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 35 bytes

```r
rep(unique(sort(c(0,scan()))),4)[4]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/vyi1QKM0L7OwNFWjOL@oRCNZw0CnODkxT0MTCHRMNKNNYv8bKxj8BwA)

Shameless port of [Sok's well-explained Pyth answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/165434/80010).

Answer (score 1):

## [Befunge-93](https://github.com/catseye/Befunge-93), 20 bytes

```
&::&*#v_&+.@
@.*!-&<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/X83KSk1LuSxeTVvPgctBT0tRV83m/39jBWMA)

### Explanation

this boils down to:

```
if(A * B = 0) {
    output (A + B)
    end
} else {
    output A * (A = B)
    end
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Shakespeare Programming Language](https://github.com/TryItOnline/spl), <s>216</s> 208 bytes

```
,.Ajax,.Ford,.Act I:.Scene I:.[Enter Ajax and Ford]Ajax:Listen tothy!Ford:Listen tothy!Am I as bad as you?If soyou zero.Is the product ofyou I worse a cat?If soyou be the sum ofyou I.If notyou zero.Open heart
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY0xC8IwEIV3f8VzL4GuXaSDQkBwcBSHtLlSxeZKckHrn4@JoOJ079777l6YbylVqr2aR6V27G3WvUA36tiToyJOWyfkURAYZ1Goc9ma/SUIOQjLuKyL/e@0EzRMQGdsGQvHjR4QOAs8ybPSATISZs825lIeSqJxZx8IBr2R30FHbzbE6cOpnDmW77fDnJtHMl5Sqlf1Cw)

As psuedo-code:

```
f(a,b):
  if a==b:
    b=0
  if a*b<1: 
    b=a+b
  else:
    b=0
  return b
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Befunge-93](https://github.com/catseye/Befunge-93), 17 bytes

```
&::&-!_&*!\&+*.@.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/X83KSk1XMV5NSzFGTVtLz0Hv/39DBQMA)

As psuedo-code:

```
f(a,b):
  if a-b==0:
    print(b)
  else:
    print((!(a*b))*(a+b))
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, <s>42</s> 34 bytes

```
lambda a,b:(0in(a,b)or a==b)*(a|b)
```

EDIT: -8 thanks to @TIO and @JonathanAllan

Comment: `a==0 or b==0` can be expressed shorter as `0 in(a,b)`. [TIO](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSFRJ8lKw0AhM08DyNLML1JItLVN0tTKTawAC/xPAwkBpRWKEvPSUzVMNK24FBRAgknoggoKBUWZeSUKYH06CmlAWgFoAAA)

Comment: Because the `max(a,b)` only has any effect when either one of `a` or `b` are zero or when `a` and `b` are equal it can be replaced by a bit-wise or: `(a|b)`. Some of your spaces are redundant too... `lambda a,b:(0in(a,b)or a==b)*(a|b)` is 34 bytes (although Dennis's 25 byte solution, [`lambda x,y:(x|y)>>(x*y&2)`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/165326/53748), also works in Python 2).

Answer (score 1):

## **JavaScript, 24 Bytes**

```
x=>y=>!x*y|!y*x|(x==y)*x
```

Allows all numbers, no conditional, doesn't require sorted input

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! I don't think this gives the right result for x=0, y=3.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG. Great first answer. But sadly this doesn't give the right answer for some values. Also to make it easier for others, you should always provide a [link for testing](https://tio.run/)

Answer (score 1):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), 27 bytes

```
N+N+N.
N+0+N.
0+N+N.
_+_+0.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKz8lP1y0uz/z/308bCPW4/LQNQJQBhBevHa9toPffXlfBACgepKNQXpRZkpqmoaRaoKCkoxAdFKupxwWWNcQra4RX1hhVNiYPWdoQr8WGeC02xGuxIX6LjfBabITXYiO8Fhvht9gYr8XGeC02xmuxMbrFcNn/AA)

The most naive translation ever.

Answer (score 1):

## [Glee](https://withglee.com/Frames/GFMain.htm), <s>24</s> <s>22</s> 20 bytes

Idea to append zero taken from Sok’s [Pyth solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/165434/39407).

`=>n,0& *>0\+ >1~ *n\>>`

```
=>n,0& *>0\+ <2*n\>>             $$<2 instead of >1~ (not > 1)
```

Explanation:

```
a b=>n,0& *>0\+ <2*n\>>
a b=>n                      3 1     2 2     0 3     0 0     assign a b to n
      ,0                    3 1 0   2 2 0   0 3 3   0 0 0   catenate 0
        &                   0 1 3   0 2     0 3     0       unique elements
          *>0               011     01      01      0       mark all > 0 (boolean)
             \+             2       1       1       0       reduce by addition
                <2          0       1       1       1       result <2 ?
                  *n        0 0     2 2     0 3     0 0     multiply with n
                    \>>     0       2       3       0       largest element
```

Old version

```
=>n--[2]=0|(n\* =0)*n\>>
```

Explanation for a pair of numbers (a b):

```
                              result for a b pairs
                               3 1    2 2    0 3
a b=>n--[2]=0|(n\* =0)*n\>>
a b                            3 1    2 2    0 3   create vector (a b)
   =>n                                             assign vector to n
      --                       0 _2   0 0    0 3   calculate the first difference vector of n (monadic --)
        [2]=0                  0      1      0     result vector at index 2 equal to 0 ? (boolean)
              (n\*             3      4      0     n reduced by multiplication
                   =0)         0      0      1     equal to 0 ? (boolean)
             |                 0      1      1     OR (boolean) (dyadic |)
                      *n       0 0    2 2    0 3   multiplied by n (dyadic *)
                        \>>    0      2      3     largest element (monadic \>>)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [QBasic 1.1](http://www.qbasic.net/), 38 bytes

```
INPUT A,B
IF A*B THEN?A*-(A=B)ELSE?A+B
```

-1 thanks to [DLosc](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/16766/dlosc).

Input is two comma-separated integers.

Answer (score 0):

## [Attache](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Attache), 32 bytes

```
{If[_=_2,_,If[Min!__,0,Max!__]]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SywpSUzOSP2fpmBl@7/aMy063jbeSCdeB8jyzcxTjI/XMdDxTawAMmJja//7paamFEerFBQkp8dyBRRl5pWEpBaXOCcWpxZHq6XpKLjlJJZE@5eWpBZFh@koGFgZg4lYHQXD2Nj/AA)

Takes input as two arguments, such as `f[0, 1] = 1`.

### Other solutions

### 34 bytes

```
{If[Same!_,_@0,If[Min!_,0,Max!_]]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SywpSUzOSP2fpmBl@7/aMy06ODE3VTFeJ97BQAfI883MA3IMdHwTKxTjY2Nr//ulpqYUR6sUFCSnx3IFFGXmlYSkFpc4JxanFken6Si45SSWRPuXlqQWRYfpKBhYGYOJWB0Fw9jY/wA) The same as above, but takes input as an array

### 39 bytes

```
{ToBase[47483073034,5][FromBase&4!_]-1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SywpSUzOSP2fpmBl@786JN8psTg12sTcxMLYwNzYwNhExzQ22q0oPxckrmaiGB@ra1j73y81NaU4WqWgIDk9liugKDOvJCS1uMQZqKQ4Ok1HwS0nsSTav7QktSg6TEfBwMoYTMTqKBjGxv4HAA)

Hardcodes the solution in a base-5 integer. More interesting IMO but longer.

Comment: Surely base 4 suffices?

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, 11 bytes

```
e+Z.-+xFQQ{
```

[Try it here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=e%2BZ.-%2BxFQQ%7B&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=0%2C%200%0A0%2C%201%0A0%2C%202%0A0%2C%203%0A1%2C%200%0A1%2C%201%0A1%2C%202%0A1%2C%203%0A2%2C%200%0A2%2C%201%0A2%2C%202%0A2%2C%203%0A3%2C%200%0A3%2C%201%0A3%2C%202%0A3%2C%203&debug=0)

#### Explanation

```
e+Z.-+xFQQ{
     +xFQQ      Prepend the XOR of the inputs to the inputs.
   .-     {Q    Remove one copy of the deduplicated (implicit) input.
 +Z             Prepend 0.
e               Take the last.
```

#### Alternative solution, 11 bytes

```
e+0.-F{B+xF
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), 10 bytes

```
-iFQ&.AQnF
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=-iFQ%26.AQnF&input=%280%2C+0%29+-%3E+0%0A%280%2C+1%29+-%3E+1%0A%280%2C+2%29+-%3E+2%0A%280%2C+3%29+-%3E+3%0A%281%2C+0%29+-%3E+1%0A%281%2C+1%29+-%3E+1%0A%281%2C+2%29+-%3E+0%0A%281%2C+3%29+-%3E+0%0A%282%2C+0%29+-%3E+2%0A%282%2C+1%29+-%3E+0%0A%282%2C+2%29+-%3E+2%0A%282%2C+3%29+-%3E+0%0A%283%2C+0%29+-%3E+3%0A%283%2C+1%29+-%3E+0%0A%283%2C+2%29+-%3E+0%0A%283%2C+3%29+-%3E+3&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=0%2C+0%0A%0A0%2C+1%0A%0A0%2C+2%0A%0A0%2C+3%0A%0A1%2C+0%0A%0A1%2C+1%0A%0A1%2C+2%0A%0A1%2C+3%0A%0A2%2C+0%0A%0A2%2C+1%0A%0A2%2C+2%0A%0A2%2C+3%0A%0A3%2C+0%0A%0A3%2C+1%0A%0A3%2C+2%0A%0A3%2C+3%0A&debug=0&input_size=2)

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 20 bytes

```javascript
a=>b=>a-b&&a*b?0:a|b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/R1i7J1i5RN0lNLVEryd7AKrEm6X9yfl5xfk6qXk5@ukaahoEmEGlyoQoa4RA0xCZohCFogE3QEJsgVu3G2Gw3xma7MQ7txticZIzNScbYnGSMw8z/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 43 bytes

```
proc M a\ b {expr !$a?$b:!$b?$a:$a-$b?0:$a}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcoxCsMwDIXhPad4AQ0ttGBLm5ecICdoMsghW0pNmkIh@OzuGzr8PH2gY9laK/trwQifkHGu37KjFx8kp17yIJ7E7zwCt7bt6eX/2QUEFpky6yId6UhHWmmllVbaaKONNrriLJ/jjYv4TfI1TXiMEIfkubYf)

Answer (score 0):

## C#, <s>48</s>27 bytes

```
(x,y)=>x==y?x:(x*y>0?0:x|y)
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##TY6xasMwEIZ3PcXhSYpd4yFTbNlDIVMChQ4ZQgZXlcMJVyqSEiTaPLsjhxgy/PDfffDdCfcmjJWTGHvn4IP8EQDne48CPqPz8qfcXrRoUPvimRYGPtFQRMbbwHnswoaGVWyrrtqE/8immpDfy9eYDE/R1eA37HvU1HmL@nw8QW/Pjj2ODcYCTVpAXtXYrGvMc5b2L0QlohJRC4Hlt3ejnRllebDo5Q61pNlAM8gBU7JibmpuDDjMw0CxUIzV5EZu0x0)

Thanks @Charlie for the TIO link & helping trim 21 chars off the code

Comment: Welcome to the site! I don't know C#, but is it possible to remove the space between `> a=`? Also, would you mind editing in a link to an online tester, such as [Try it online!](https://tio.run/#) so that others can test your submission?

Comment: You can use [this link](https://tio.run/##TY6xasMwEIZ3PcXhSYpd4yFTbNlDIVMChQ4ZQgZXlcMJVyqSEiTaPLsjhxgy/PDfffDdCfcmjJWTGHvn4IP8EQDne48CPqPz8qfcXrRoUPvimRYGPtFQRMbbwHnswoaGVWyrrtqE/8immpDfy9eYDE/R1eA37HvU1HmL@nw8QW/Pjj2ODcYCTVpAXtXYrGvMc5b2L0QlohJRC4Hlt3ejnRllebDo5Q61pNlAM8gBU7JibmpuDDjMw0CxUIzV5EZu0x0) in your answer, which also reduces your byte-count to just 27 bytes, as a simple lambda expression is a valid answer in code golf.

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing I have now included TIO link to my answer (Thanks to @Charlie). the space (and the variable) apparently seems to be not required, I wasn't aware on the guidelines around how to use lambda expressions for code golf answers, thanks again to Charlie for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 4 bytes

-1 thanks to [H.PWiz](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/71256/h-pwiz).

```
!4uΘ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hci7DYAwDEDBWehd@MM2lvtIiAplAJiCqRiCRRzpNVfcmNfR5//cve3ze7s7U0VL0tAxUMV444033nnnnXc@@OCDj6oF)

Answer (score 0):

## 12-basic, 36 bytes

```
FUNC M(A,B)?(A or B)*(!A~!B|A==B)END
```

This can probably be shortened.

`~` is bitwise XOR (as well as bitwise NOT when used as a unary operator) (Just like in Lua)

Comment: Please link to implementation in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 28 bytes

```
[pq]sqsidli=qd0rli*0!=qli++p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@b6xg@D@6oDC2uLA4MyUn07YwxaAoJ1PLQNG2MCdTW7vg/38A)

I'll keep mulling over this, it feels like it must be golfable. `[pq]sq` just makes a print & quit macro. `sidli` stores one of our values in the register `i`, duplicates the other value, and then recalls `i`. `=q` consumes two values on the stack, and executes macro `q` if they're equal (so, prints the one value left behind). `d0r` duplicates the value on the stack again, and then puts a `0` on the stack in between them. `li*0!=` loads `i`, multiplies the two values, and runs `q` to print the `0` that we left on the stack if the two values were not equal. If none of these things has happened yet, we `li` to load `i`, and we now have three values on the stack - two zeroes and our one non-zero value. `++` add the three together, and `p`rint.

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 25 bytes

```perl
/ /;$_=($'|$`)>>($'*$`&2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/19fQd9aJd5WQ0W9RiVB084OyNBSSVAz0vz/30jB6F9@QUlmfl7xf90CAA)

Steals the method from @Dennis's Python answer.

Answer (score 0):

## **PHP - 52 bytes**

```
<?=($a=$argv[1])==($b=$argv[2])?$a:($a*$b?0:$a|$b);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt5WQyXRViWxKL0s2jBW0xbITYJyjWI17VUSrYDyWipJ9gZWKok1Kkma1lz///83/m/8L7@gJDM/r/i/bopCcUZ@UUl8fkFqXnxJYrptfh4A)

Explanation:

```
$a==$b  Check for equality, display first value if equal
$a*$b   If multiplication equates to non-zero, display 0 (Unknown) else...
$a|$b   Display the non-zero value.
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, <s>42</s> 40 bytes

```php
[,$a,$b]=$argv;echo$a*$b&&$a-$b?0:$a|$b;
```

Run with `php -r '<code>' <a> <b>` or [Try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ab71add5283093f5fd4d31b48d45a968a8fc58f6).

**breakdown**

```php
[,$a,$b]=$argv; // import input
echo
    $a*$b       // if both not 0
    &&$a-$b     // and unequal
        ?0      // then print 0
        :$a|$b  // else print the non-zero value, if there is one
;
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Q'Nial7](https://github.com/danlm/qnial7), 40 bytes

```
n is OP A B{2>sum(cull A B 0>0)*max A B}

n is OP A B{                           }    operation n with parameters A B (pair of numbers)
                       A B 0                append 0 to pair of numbers
                  cull                      create list of unique elements
                            >0              create booleans of elements that are > 0
              sum(            )             sum up the booleans
            2>                              sum > 2 ? (boolean)
                               *max A B     multiply boolean with max of A B
```

result:

```
     n 0 3
3
     n 1 2
0
     n 2 2
2
     n 0 0
0
```